# "Element style not allowed as child of element form"

Tags: html, w3c-validation

For some reason I am getting an error that says:

> Element `style` not allowed as child of element `form` in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
>
> Line:  17

Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en-US"><head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form method="post" spellcheck="true" action="http://www.ijdky.net">


    <input name="text" class="name" placeholder="Please Enter Name">
    <!-- This Part is Where the user will type their name for the comment section-->

    <br> <!-- Break -->
    <br> <!-- Break -->

    <style type="text/css"> textarea.html-text-box {background-color:white;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-attachment:fixed;border-width:4;border-style:solid;border-color:black;font-family:Georgia;font-size:16pt;color:black;}
input.html-text-box {background-color:ffffff;font-family:Georgia;font-size:12pt;color:000000;}
    </style> <!-- The Comment Box -->
    <textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="10" class="html-text-box">            </textarea>

    <br> <!-- Break -->
    <br> <!-- Break -->

    <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" class="html-text-box">

    <br> <!-- Break -->
    <br> <!-- Break -->

    <input type="reset" value="Reset Comment" class="html-text-box">

    </form>
    </body>
    </html

    <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->

    <!-- language: lang-html -->

    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en-US"><head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form method="post" spellcheck="true" action="http://www.ijdky.net">


    <input name="text" class="name" placeholder="Please Enter Name">
    <!-- This Part is Where the user will type their name for the comment section-->

    <br> <!-- Break -->
    <br> <!-- Break -->

    <style type="text/css"> textarea.html-text-box {background-color:white;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-attachment:fixed;border-width:4;border-style:solid;border-color:black;font-family:Georgia;font-size:16pt;color:black;}
    input.html-text-box {background-color:ffffff;font-family:Georgia;font-size:12pt;color:000000;}
    </style> <!-- The Comment Box -->
    <textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="10" class="html-text-box"></textarea>

    <br> <!-- Break -->
    <br> <!-- Break -->

    <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" class="html-text-box">

    <br> <!-- Break -->
    <br> <!-- Break -->

    <input type="reset" value="Reset Comment" class="html-text-box">

    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have searched everywhere and cannot find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Move this:

`<style type="text/css"> textarea.html-text-box {background-color:white;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-attachment:fixed;border-width:4;border-style:solid;border-color:black;font-family:Georgia;font-size:16pt;color:black;}
input.html-text-box {background-color:ffffff;font-family:Georgia;font-size:12pt;color:000000;}
</style>`

to the `<head>` element.

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved my problem.  Something so single can drive a person crazy.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is putting the `<style>` tag in the wrong place. Put all your `<style>` declarations in the `<head>` part of the document. According to [the HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-style-element), that's where it has to go.

Comment: Thanks.  This worked.  Are you a real expert with HTML5.  If so where should I go to learn more about it.  I am trying to creating  a website and not sure how to link css page with the HTML page.

Comment: @DeQuanLynch - The Mozilla site [Web technology for developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) is a great place to start.